# How can I modify the following HTML code for creating an email?

Tags: javascript, html

The following code enables users to create an email by clicking on a button.

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Contact Us"
 onClick="parent.location='mailto:you@youremail.com?subject=The subject you want to appear&body=I loveyou&cc=you2@youremail.com'">
</FORM>
```

I want to replace the button with an image instead, so that when somebody clicks on the image they will be able to create the email.

Can you please advise me how i should modify the code?

Comment: Code seems to be missing. Pls check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="#"> <img onClick="parent.location='mailto:you@youremail.com?subject=The subject you want to appear&body=I loveyou&cc=you2@youremail.com'" src="contactus.png" alt="Contact Us" /> </a>
```

**Note:** set the `src` with your image URL.

Answer (score 0):

You may change "type" to "Image" like:

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="Image" SRC="../images/submit.gif" Alt="Contact Us"
 onClick="parent.location='mailto:you@youremail.com?subject=The subject you want to appear&body=I loveyou&cc=you2@youremail.com'">
</FORM>
```